# Why weren't these characters' faces shown in Ahsoka S1E5?

Tags: star-wars, ahsoka-series

In *Ahsoka* Season 1 Episode 5, "Shadow Warrior", there's a sequence where

> Ahsoka finds herself in a vision of a Clone Wars battle with Anakin. After some fighting, they're in a field hospital of sorts with medical droids and wounded clone troopers.

I noticed that in this scene,

> all of the helmetless clone troopers have cloths fully covering their faces, presumably for injury or air quality reasons. This struck me as an unusual dramatic decision—the sequence is a clear callback to *The Clone Wars*, where the clone troopers tend to show their faces fairly often, and the focus of the dialogue in the scene is Ahsoka's sense of responsibility for their lives, so depicting them as "faceless" seems at odds with these aspects of the scene.

My first thought was that it was due to

> Temuera Morrison being unavailable, but he apparently [voices Rex](https://www.themarysue.com/who-is-captain-rex-in-ahsoka-explained/) during the scene. I also considered that it might have been meant to show that Ahsoka and Anakin were the only "real people" in the flashback, since they're some sort of Force spirit projection and everyone else is illusory, but the Twi'leks in the background all appeared to be normal.

Has this been discussed by anyone working on the show?

Comment: He can still *voice* Rex, but he must look quite a bit older now.

Comment: Speculation: it's probably both to hide Temuera's face (and sidestep the CGI work to fake it) and ALSO because this is supposed to be a sort of "dream sequence"; not exactly what happened, but what Ahsoka remembers now.

Comment: also - that 'faceless' idea ties nicely with the overall view of the clones as essentially created to be canon fodder with no consideration for any personality or life they may want or have beyond that was explored often in Clone Wars series

Comment: I noticed that the face of the clone trooper who is being treated by the 2-1B is not fully covered. The trooper wears a kind of balaclava that exposes part of his face including his eyes.

Answer (score 4):

There's no definitive answer (yet) largely because anyone on the production that could talk about it are currently on strike and thus can't. However there's a few educated guesses one could make, that broadly speaking amount to the same thing: budget.

Last I checked Temuera Morrison still lives in New Zealand, so assuming he wasn't  already in town during the shoot; getting him on a plane to just shoot one scene where he lies on a stretcher with no lines really isn't worth his time and inconvenience. Conversely if they paid him enough to make it worth his time, well that would be a needless and rather extravagant expense for the production. And even if he was in town; they'd have to digitally de-age him too which is likewise a needless expense. Just digitally comping his face onto the doubles would again cost money, and add nothing of value to the scene.
Either way, it's much easier (and cheaper) to just have the in-costume performers keep their helmets on/faces covered, while Morrison can record his lines in a booth from literally anywhere in the world.
It's also worth noting that this show needs to work just as well for long term fans that get the references as it does for brand new fans. What we got was the right balance of fan service cameo and what was right, and objectively make sense for the scene.

Comment: I wonder for such a short shot/sequence, why not have people that look vaguely similar to Temuera (not too much, either)? Like you said: new fans don't even know what his face looks like, and it doesn't resemble the cartoons anyway (this is important: Temuera's face looks very little like all the clones in the cartoons, Clone Wars, Rebels, Bad Batch, etc). And long term fans won't care much for such a short shot.

Comment: @AndresF. Counterpoint: after going to the trouble and expense of making actual physical Phase 1 Clonetrooper helmets for the first time ever, why waste them by having people wandering around with them off? The real question here is; why bother showing the clones' faces at all when they're basically set dressing so far as the needs of the scene are concerned? Why pull focus away from Ahsoka and Anakin just so a percentage of the audience get impersonate that Leo DiCaprio meme?

Comment: oh, I agree. The helmets would have been fine, too. My point is that you don't really need to show Temuera's face either way.